# How can I inject a property which is dependent upon another value in Guice 4.1?

Tags: java, guice

I have a service consumed by several modules and in each module, it defines its own provider for providing that value which depends on another value.  Rather than have all the other values in that object, I would prefer to work directly with that single value, but there is no way to use Guice's bindConstant() to a provider.

Current Psuedo code:

```
ConfigurationProvider implements Provider<Configuration> {
    final Configuration configuration;
    @Inject
    public ConfigurationProvider(BuildConfiguration buildConfiguration) {
        configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.setDownloadPath(buildConfiguration.getBuildPath() + File.separator + "downloads");
    }

    public Configuration get() {
        return configuration;
    }
}
```

Inside the module:

```
bind(Configuration.class).toProvider(ConfigurationProvider.class);
```

Instead, I'd like to use my property injection where possible and just do something like this:

```
    DownloadPathProvider implements Provider<Property<DownloadPath, String>> {
     final String downloadPath;
     @Inject public DownloadPathProvider(BuildConfiguration buildConfiguration) {
      downloadPath = buildConfiguration.getBuildPath() + File.separator + "downloads";
     }

     public String get() {
         return downloadPath;
     }
}
```

I believe the problem is that for bindConstant to work, I need to have that value already determined when the module is initialized.  But the value in this case is derived later (actually through another provider).

While it works with putting the configuration in a simple pojo, I feel it would be a little more succinct to work directly with the property, than nest it in a pojo.

The configuration or value is effectively a constant because once it is set, it will never change.  I merely want to base that value off of another value.

Comment: If that value is "determined when the module is initialized" then the value is *not a constant*.

Comment: A more effective question might be something like: "What is an easy way to inject startup / configuration settings in Guice?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I wanted to be able to directly inject primitive types, I had to get creative ...

1. Declare a ComputedProperty interface as a subinterface of ConfigurableProperty
2. Implement a ComputedPropertySource which has access to already set properties.  The ComputedPropertySource will have a lower priority and will run after other property sources have already run.
3. Exclude ComputedProperty from other property lookups
4. Extend this interface for any properties that need to be "computed"

At runtime, the property sources are run in order, with computed properties running last.

It is a bit hackish, I'll see if I can clean this up a bit more then post the code to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

This value is not a constant if it is not fixed at module creation time. It is actually a Singleton. Instead of using `bindConstant()`, just `bind().in(Scope.Singleton)`.